# Pointer? Pointer Function?

Tags: c++, pointers

i recently started coding and I've been trying to figure out what this means for a while:
`static thing* dostuff();
thing* thing::dostuff(){};`
I searched function pointers but they look different. These types of functions seem to come up in important areas of code and I'd like to know what they mean and how to use them. thanks you.

Comment: It's a function that returns a pointer.

Comment: Read up on [tag:pointers]

Comment: My crystal ball tells me the first was in a class definition for some class `thing`, the latter in some implementing source file. And the latter is lying, as it claims to return a `thing` pointer and in reality does nothing. Both of these are functions that return pointers. Function-pointers have *nothing* to do with this.

Comment: A piece on function pointers to help you recognize the difference (and a small warning about the difference between functions and member functions): https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/pointers-to-members

Comment: @WhozCraig to be fair, there's no "function pointer" in OP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code fragments `static thing* dostuff()` and `thing* thing::dostuff(){}` have nothing to do with function pointers, but are the declaration of a function and the definition/implementation of this function.

`static thing* dostuff();` declares a function that returns a pointer of data type `thing`, which is probably a class type.

So it's very likely that `dostuff` is actually a member function defined in a class `thing`. Keyword static declares members that are not bound to class instances, and static member functions are not associated with any object. When called, they have no `this`-pointer:

```
class thing {
  static thing* dostuff();
};
```

Then, `thing* thing::dostuff(){}` is the implementation of this static member function of class `thing`. Prefix `thing::` denotes that this function is part of class `thing`.

Answer (score 0):

It's just a static member function of `thing`, called `dostuff`, returning a pointer of type `thing*`.

There's nothing special or weird about it.